# Why can't we make an inverse infinite series function of a polynomial equation with degree greater than/equal to 5 using LaGrange's inversion theorem?

Tags: calculus

Consider a polynomial function of degree 5: $$f(x) = ax^5 + bx^4 +cx^3 +dx^2 +ex +f = 0$$
similarly as to how we use Lagrange's inversion theorem to find the infinite series expansion of the inverse of the function $f(x)=x\cdot e^x$ i.e the Lambert $W$ function, why can't we find the inverse function of polynomial functions like these to find the approximate roots of the function instead? (Because there's no general formula to find the roots of polynomial function greater than degree 5.)

Comment: You can. What you heard that sounds like "there is no general formula" is not like that. The theorem is that there is not "formula in radicals". Follow [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) for the precise definition, or more directly [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_in_radicals).

Answer (score 4):

The Abel-Ruffini theorem you are referring to does not state that there can not be a general formula. It states that there cannot be a formula using only radicals (i.e. integer roots). You can totally expand the inverse in a point $x_0$ as long as $f'(x_0) \neq 0$. For example, the expansion for the inverse of $f(x) = x^5 - x$ is given by
$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty} {5k \choose k} \frac{(-x)^{4k+1}}{4k+1}.$$

Comment: What's its ratius of convergence btw? Is $R=|c^5-c|$ with $c=1/\sqrt[4]{5}$ or something like that?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[k]{{5k \choose k}\frac{1}{4k+1}} = \frac{5^5}{4^4}$, so the convergence radius will be $\frac{4}{5^{5/4}}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It is the same value I got $R\approx0.535$, which is the $y$-coordinate of the critical points of $f$.